# Trouble with deserialising a file stored in android

Tags: java, android, serialization, deserialization, indexoutofboundsexception

I have been having some trouble with storing and retrieving my ArrayLists to a device's internal storage. I have a custom serializer/deserializer which I have been using successfully with storing and retrieving data from SharedPreferences. However, I am unable to get it to work with files stored on the device's internal storage. I have needed to make this step as my date was becoming too large for SharedPreferences.

I would very much appreciate some help on this issue. There may well be a glaring problem with my code as I am quite new to this and have never tried storing and retrieving from Android internal storage before (trying it out as a hobby). Any help would be much appreciated...

Is there a blatant problem? Is there a much better way of doing this?

The serialiser/deserialiser is this:

```
package com.ctech.dailybread.io;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ObjectSerializer {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ObjectSerializer.class);

public static String serialize(Serializable obj) throws IOException {
    if (obj == null) return "";
    ByteArrayOutputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream objStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serialObj);
    objStream.writeObject(obj);
    objStream.close();
    return encodeBytes(serialObj.toByteArray());
}

public static Object deserialize(String str) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) return null;
    ByteArrayInputStream serialObj = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodeBytes(str));
    ObjectInputStream objStream = new ObjectInputStream(serialObj);
    return objStream.readObject();
}

public static String encodeBytes(byte[] bytes) {
    StringBuffer strBuf = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
        strBuf.append((char) (((bytes[i]) & 0xF) + ((int) 'a')));
    }

    return strBuf.toString();
}

public static byte[] decodeBytes(String str) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[str.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i+=2) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        bytes[i/2] = (byte) ((c - 'a') << 4);
        c = str.charAt(i+1);
        bytes[i/2] += (c - 'a');
    }
    return bytes;
}

}
```

The storage method I am using is:

```
public static void storeToFile(Context ctx, String fileName, ArrayList input) {
    String fileName2 = fileName + ".ser";
    try (
        OutputStream os = ctx.openFileOutput(fileName2, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStream buffer = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
        ObjectOutput output = new ObjectOutputStream(buffer);
        ){
          output.writeChars(ObjectSerializer.serialize(input));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And on loading a file, in this case, a list of 'Day' objects:

```
public static ArrayList<Day> loadDayListFromFile(Context ctx) {
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = ctx.openFileInput("dayList.ser");
        try {
            Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF8"));
            dayList = (ArrayList<Day>) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(reader.toString());
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Toaster.toastItShort("Unable to load day list", ctx);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Toaster.toastItShort("Could not find day list file", ctx);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return dayList;
}
```

When the file is loaded, which at this point contains and empty ArrayList it throws a fatal ArrayIndexOutOfBounds error:

> 02-11 13:24:43.460 18966-18966/com.ctech.dailybread E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                         Process: com.ctech.dailybread, PID: 18966
>                                                                         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ctech.dailybread/com.ctech.dailybread.activities.ProgressDetail}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=15
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>                                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=15; index=15
>                                                                             at com.ctech.dailybread.io.ObjectSerializer.decodeBytes(ObjectSerializer.java:66)...

... referring to this line in the object serializer ...

```
bytes[i/2] = (byte) ((c - 'a') << 4);
```

Comment: Suggestion: learn about unit testing. Obviously your code is wrong under certain inputs (the exception tells you that you are using an invalid index; probably because / 2 ... might not always give you the exact number of bytes you need). Such stuff is perfect for unit testing. You can test all of that inside your eclipse; you do not need to put any "android" into consideration. Side question: why are all your methods public?